# Obtain Image From Json File and Display it as ImageOverlay in Leafleat

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet

I'm trying to obtain an image from my json file and I want to display it on the map.

This is what the Json looks like:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": 0,
  "properties": {
    "NAME": "Building",
    "FLOOR_IMG_1": "assets/img/floor-plan1.svg",
    "FLOOR_IMG_2": "assets/img/floor-plan2.svg"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [100, 10]
  }
}
```

I want to display the "FLOOR_IMG_1" and "FLOOR_IMG_2".

I tried this code but it's not working

```
$.getJSON("data/building.geojson", function (data) {
    var imageUrl = feature.properties.FLOOR_IMG_1,
    imageBounds = [
      [0, 0],
      [250, 250],
    ];
    image = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(imageBounds);
});
```

Comment: Pal, if you want to use `$.`, you got to load jquery properly.

Comment: @IvanSanchez I tried adding jquery, but the code still not working. I don't know if the code really works

Comment: Do read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery, `$.getJSON` is jQuery method

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I tried adding jquery, but the code still not working. I don't know if the code really works

Comment: Try with document ready

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("data/building.geojson", function (data) { var imageUrl = feature.properties.FLOOR_IMG_1, imageBounds = [ [0, 0], [250, 250], ]; image = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map); map.fitBounds(imageBounds); });
});

Comment: It seems like it can't read: feature.properties.FLOOR_IMG_1, the error states that feature is not defined.

Comment: Change feature.properties to data.properties